# Software install GPO on server 2012 (not R2) is not being deployed to windows 8 and 8.1 clients but is being deployed to windows 7 clients

Tags: group-policy

I am trying to deploy some management MSI files via GPO running on Server 2012 (not R2) and the GPOs aren't being deployed to the Windows 8 and 8.1 clients.  However the GPO is is working fine to the windows 7 clients.

I've run gpresults /h gpreport.html and I checked and the GPO isn't in the report on any of the Windows 8 and 8.1 clients.  The GPO does appear in the report on the Windows 7 clients.

Will have I have to upgrade the domain controllers to Server 2012 **R2** to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a WMI filter attached to your GPO? If you run `gpresult /r` on your client machine it should show you _why_ a policy was not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  As it turns out the auto install is GPO linked a security group. Once I added the computer to the security group the GPO got applied.

Now I didn't set things up like this.  So it may have been my predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

The functional level of the domain controller. You may need it to be raised for Windows 8 to deploy properly.

Run rsop.msc on the Windows 8 machines to make sure the group police is being pushed to the Windows 8 machines

Make sure the Windows 8 machines are in the right Org Unit and that block policy inheritance is not turned on.

You might try installing RSAT for Windows 8, logging in as a Domain controller, and then configuring the Group policy that way. I have seen it cause certain settings to work when using a newer version of group policy manager.

Comment: Thanks Super1337 for your fast reply! The domain and the forest level is set to Server 2012. I ran rsop.msc of a Windows 8.1 client and the software install GPO is not being pushed. I then ran rsop.msc on a Windows 7 client and the software install GPO is being pushed. I checked and block policy is not turned on.
I actually use RSAT on my Windows 8.1 system to admin the servers.

Comment: Are the Windows 8 machines in the same OU? Your functional level may need to be 2012 r2